# How do I reserve RAM on a PowerPC CPU running Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, embedded, powerpc, u-boot

I am trying to reserve 10MB out of the 2GB onboard RAM on an embedded single-board computer that uses the Canyonlands (PowerPC-460EX) CPU. By reserve RAM, I mean block out a chunk of RAM that Linux will not touch so it will retain data on a warm-reboot. I am using the U-Boot bootloader, and I have tried the following methods:

1) Set mem=2038M in the bootargs envinronment variable
2) Set the 'pram' environment variable in U-Boot and then set mem=\${mem} in bootargs

Both methods failed to change the RAM seen by Linux. I am looking at /proc/meminfo to figure out how much RAM Linux sees as available. In both cases, /proc/meminfo sees 2074876 kB of RAM available (just under 2GB).

Any ideas?

Comment: Extra info: Linux kernel is v2.6.30.3, U-boot is 2009.08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment, but here are some clues:

1) Check that your mem parameter is being passed correctly to the kernel. You should be able to do this using `cat /proc/cmdline` after you boot as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32654/how-do-i-find-the-boot-parameters-used-by-the-running-kernel).

2) Try using quotes around your parameters like "mem=2038M".

Comment: I am giving you credit for the answer, because you led me in the right direction. Thanks! Basically, the problem was that the bootargs environment variable in U-boot was getting overwritten by the usbdrive_args variable. Looking at /proc/cmdline helped me figure out that bootargs wasn't getting passed to the kernel!

Comment: I guess all you needed to do then was that usbdrive_args appended to the bootargs instead of replacing them.